# Call Stack vs Intermodular Calls in Ollydbg

Tags: debugging, ollydbg

What is the difference between call stack and intermodular calls. Could you clarify the difference between the two? For example if I need to catch message box API function, do these methods serve the same purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are completely different things.

**Call stack** window shows such information as stack frame for each function call in the current thread, including arguments passed, name of callee and the (virtual) address where it was called from.

**Intermodular calls** window, on the other hand, shows all calls to the *external* (API) functions in the current module.

That being said, if you want to find message box function, you can do it by opening *Intermodular calls* window, clicking *Destination* button (that will sort functions by name) and you may set breakpoints on each place this function is called, like presented in the image below:[image: ollyDbg_Intermodular_calls]

Of course pick your desired function name instead of atoi.

Comment: What if _Intermodular calls_ window shows less functions. I attached the application and press _Run_. The _Destination_ section shows almost nothing (nothing helpful)

Comment: Check if you are in the right module when right clicking->Intermodular calls, i.e. in the module you want to get calls from.

Comment: Can I use the Names window to find the message box function as well?

Comment: I think that you should be able to find it this way.